# winston-elasticsearch: TypeError: Elasticsearch is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, express, elasticsearch, logging, winston

I'm using winston-elasticsearch on an express server, I just wrote the same code as in the documentation

```
var winston = require('winston');
var Elasticsearch = require('winston-elasticsearch');

var esTransportOpts = {
  level: 'info'
};
var logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new Elasticsearch(esTransportOpts)
  ]
});
```

when i run the server, I get this error:

> TypeError: Elasticsearch is not a constructor

I have installed the lates versions "winston": "^3.2.1" and "winston-elasticsearch": "^0.8.8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Winston 3.x, Elasticsearch 6.0 and later, use the 0.7.0. For Elasticsearch 6.0 and later, use the 0.6.0. For Elasticsearch 5.0 and later, use the 0.5.9. For earlier versions, use the 0.4.x series.

Answer (score 5):

@asma's suggestion, downgrade to 0.7.x, did indeed fix this error for me. However, that left me stuck at an outdated version, getting a different error that is fixed in the latest version.

The issue mentioned by @joe is closed now. It explains that everyone's gotten used to the breaking change by adjusting their syntax. However, the README still has the old syntax.

I was able to get the latest version (0.8.8) working by adjusting the example as follows:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var winstonElasticSearch = require('winston-elasticsearch');

var esTransportOpts = {
  level: 'info'
};
var logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winstonElasticSearch.ElasticsearchTransport(esTransportOpts)
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade version "winston-elasticsearch": "0.7.0" fixes the problem.

As mentionned in documentation:

> Compatibility For Winston 3.x, Elasticsearch 6.0 and later, use the
>   0.7.0. For Elasticsearch 6.0 and later, use the 0.6.0. For Elasticsearch 5.0 and later, use the 0.5.9. For earlier versions, use
>   the 0.4.x series.

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-elasticsearch

Answer (score 2):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/vanthome/winston-elasticsearch/issues/131) regarding precisely this.

In the meantime, you can do `npm i --save winston-elasticsearch@0.7.12`.